# Is anyone able to identify these two pieces?

Tags: part-identification, minifigure-identification

I'm struggling to identify these two parts. I have searched all parts on Rebrickable, but without any luck. Is someone out there able to help me?

[image]

Answer (score 18):

These are [Skeleton Arm #4](https://brickset.com/parts/design-93609):

[image]

and [Skeleton Leg](https://brickset.com/parts/design-31733):

[image]

Comment: Mostly from Minecraft sets.